# infinite integral does not yield the correct answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to perform the following integration:

$$\int\limits_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{r \sqrt{\left(r^2-m\right) \left(\frac{r^2}{\text{r0}^2}-1\right)}} \, dr$$

(`m` and `r0` are constants) and get the below simplified answer
$$\frac{\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{m}+\text{r0}}{\text{r0}-\sqrt{m}}\right)}{\sqrt{m}}$$

I can't get the above answer.  The `Integrate` commands yield a complicated answer which has no similarity to the simplified answer.

The Code for its definite integral is

```
Integrate[1/(r Sqrt[(r^2 - m) (r^2/r0^2 - 1)]), r]
```

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Comment: I added the definite integral code but its indefinite one say that the integral does converge on specified interval.

Comment: You can use `Assumptions` as an option to `Integrate` to give it more information about your parameters/variables. E.g. `Assumptions->{r0>0,r>r0,r>m}` to get possibly simpler answers.

Comment: Also with your current code example, you are asking Mathematica for an indefinite integral, whereas in your original formula you are interested in a definite integral with infinite limits, which can be much easier to compute in many cases. You can use `Integrate[1/(r Sqrt[(r^2 - m) (r^2/r0^2 - 1)]), {r,0,Infinity}]` to get the equivalent in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

If you change some parameters, you get the desired result.

Integrating von 0 to Infinity gives you the message, that it doesn't converge.

```
int0[r0_, m_] = 
  Integrate[1/(r Sqrt[(r^2 - m) (r^2/r0^2 - 1)]), {r, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < r0 && m < r0]

(*     Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/(r Sqrt[(-m+r^2) (-1+r^2/r0^2)]) 
       does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}. >>     *)
```

Numerical integration begining from r0 gives a good result

```
nint[r0_, m_] := 
   NIntegrate[1/(r Sqrt[(r^2 - m) (r^2/r0^2 - 1)]), {r, r0, Infinity}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 200] // Quiet

Plot[nint[1, m], {m, -5, 2}]
```

[image]

If you correct your simplified answer by a factor of 1/2, you get the same picture (not shown here)

```
simAnswer[r0_, m_] = Log[(Sqrt[m] + r0)/(-Sqrt[m] + r0)]/(2 Sqrt[m])

Plot[simAnswer[1, m], {m, -5, 2}]
```

Both imply that m has to be m < r0

Integrate with this assumptions

```
int[r0_, m_] = 
   Integrate[1/(r Sqrt[(r^2 - m) (r^2/r0^2 - 1)]), {r, r0, Infinity}, 
      Assumptions -> 0 < r0 && m < r0]

(*     (-ArcTanh[1 - (2 m)/r0^2] + 2 ArcTanh[r0/Sqrt[m]] + 
         Log[-(Sqrt[-m + r0^2]/Sqrt[m])])/(2 Sqrt[m])     *)
```

Plot again gives the same result (not shown here)

```
Plot[int[1, m], {m, -5, 2}]
```

Unfortunately MMA doesn't manage to show the difference is zero

```
fs[r0_, m_] = 
   FullSimplify[int[r0, m] - simAnswer[r0, m] // ExpToTrig, 
      0 < r0 && m < r0]

(*     -(1/(2 Sqrt[m]))(ArcTanh[1 - (2 m)/r0^2] - 2 ArcTanh[r0/Sqrt[m]] + 
      Log[(Sqrt[m] + r0)/(-Sqrt[m] + r0)] - 
      Log[-(Sqrt[-m + r0^2]/Sqrt[m])])     *)
```

But a grafik shows both results are equal

```
Plot[int[1, m] - simAnswer[1, m], {m, -5, .99}, MaxRecursion -> 8, 
   PlotPoints -> 500, Exclusions -> {0}, PlotRange -> 10^-14]
```

[image]